# How can I grab the wall feed of a logged in user's friends' groups?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

The Graph API is currently not allowing me to grab the wall feed of groups that the currently logged in user's friends belong to. I'm able to see the feed if I navigate to the group manually, but the Graph API is not allowing me to access the feed. The documentation states that the feed (wall) can be accessed with any valid access_token, user_groups, or friends_groups (provided that the group has privacy settings set to OPEN). Is this an error in the documentation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. Turns out I just needed to give the app the "read_stream" extended permission to access the wall feed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify whether you are having trouble accessing the list of groups itself, or just the wall feed of the groups. You also don't specify whether the friend account is itself a user of your app. In any event, it is not always the case that Facebook Graph API lets you access any information which you could access directly from http://facebook.com.